# The set of functions which makes a matrix positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a matrix $A$ whose elements are $A_{ij} = \Phi(\max(x_i,x_j)) $ where we have 
$ x_i \geq 0$ and $ x_j \geq 0$  for $ i,j=1,2,...n$. 
I need to find the set of functions $\Phi$ which makes the matrix $A$ positive semi-definite. I have not encountered such a problem before, I do not even know how to start.

Comment: Are you supposed to find all such functions for a given vector $x$, or the functions for which the matrix is positive definite for all $x$?

Comment: for the functions for which the matrix is positive definite for all $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering the $1\times1$ case, argue that $\Phi$ must be nonnegative. By considering the $2\times2$ case, argue that $\Phi$ must be monotonic decreasing. Now show that for a general $n$, if $\Phi$ is nonnegative and monotonic decreasing, then $A=\left(\Phi\left(\max(x_i,x_j)\right)\right)_{i,j=1}^n$ is positive semidefinite for any $x_1,\ldots,x_n\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer by considering $x=(x_1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: And there is a lesson: When faced with an unusual problem, look for the simplest special cases first and see where they lead you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not asked in the question but I wonder. How can we proceed if we need to find all such functions for a given vector $x$ ?

Comment: That case does not seem so simple. Of course, the answer would depend only on $\Phi(x_i)$ for $i=1,...,n$. (I should perhaps have realized before asking that this is not the likely interpretation.)